# How to run batch file using python script?

Tags: python, batch-file

Is this possible? I yes, can anyone help me how to do it. I don't know how to use  `subprocess` and `Popen()` to run my `sort.bat` file.

Comment: Did you read `subprocess`'s [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to understand how it works?

Comment: @DeepSpace I tried reading it but I'm still confused on how to apply it to run a batch file/process. But it's okay now. I tried the code from Farhan's answer. But if you have a more comprehensive explanation of the `subprocess` and `Popen()` codes than the documentation, I would be glad to hear from you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `os.system`:

```
import os
os.system('Path to your .bat file')
```